# Caffe framework: How can I solve this error?

Tags: caffe

I started to use Caffe framework on Linux as non-admin, Caffe was installed on my account. I went to usr/local/caffe path and started to run a cifar10 example by `./create_cifar10.sh`.But I got this error:

```
./create_cifar10.sh: 12: ./create_cifar10.sh: ./build/examples/cifar10/convert_cifar_data.bin: not found
```

I have checked the build directory and there is file named `convert_cifar_data.bin`there. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should execute the script 'create_cifar10.sh' from the $CAFFE_ROOT directory.

cd $CAFFE_ROOT

./examples/cifar10/create_cifar10.sh